# MoviePy for Animated Layer Compositing

Tags: python, moviepy

As an After Effects user, I've been looking at MoviePy to automate much of the work that I do.  I've done some reading, but there are still some very important features that I'm not sure if I would have control over when using MoviePy as a way to create animations.  Specifically, I'm looking to be able to control:

- Temporal keyframe interpolation for scaling, rotation, and most other animated effects that can be applied to individual layers
- Layer blending between clips after said effects have been applied

For example, something I might do in After Effects would be to take two image files, animate the one on top scaling up, the one on bottom rotating, and then using a "hard light" blending mode between them (throughout the entirety of the time that the animations are occurring).

Would I be able to do something like this in MoviePy?  If so, where should I start?

Answer (score -1):

I am working on a project that uses moviepy to edit and add overlays automatically to videos, and what you describe it is absolutely possible.
I recommend you to read the moviepy [documentation](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html).
[Here](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/06/07/a-covers-mix-with-python/) you can see an example of a project using moviepy to create a musical video clip.